# How to avoid duplicating the creation of dynamic component with the same information angular8

Tags: angular, angular8

I am developing a chat application. I have a list of users. When you click on each one, a box will appear with the messages that each one has sent. For this, I create a dynamic component for each click to a user, where that user's id is sent by parameters and with a service I get all their messages. My problem is that if the same user is clicked twice, that component is duplicated with the same information. How can I avoid duplication? The idea is that if I click on a user whose chat box is being displayed, do not create another component with that information. I need some way to validate that.

app.component.ts

```
import { Component,ViewChild,ViewContainerRef,ComponentFactoryResolver,ComponentRef,OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { ConversacionComponent} from "./components/conversacion/conversacion.component";
import {ChatService} from "./services/chat.service";
import {Mensaje} from "./models/mensaje";

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
    providers:[ChatService]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnDestroy {

    @ViewChild('componentsContainer', { read: ViewContainerRef, static: false }) container: ViewContainerRef;
    private subs: Subscription[] = [];

    public id_usuario_destino:number;
    public personas:Array<any>;
    public id_persona:number;
    public mensajes:Mensaje[];

    ngOnDestroy() {
        // unsubscribe from all on destroy
        this.subs.forEach(sub => sub.unsubscribe());

    }

    onClickAdd = (elemento) => {
        this.id_usuario_destino=elemento.id;
        this.id_persona=this.id_usuario_destino;
        this._chatService.getMessages(1,this.id_usuario_destino).subscribe(
            response=>{
                if(response.mensajes){
                    this.mensajes=response.mensajes;

                    const factory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(ConversacionComponent);
                    const component = this.container.createComponent(factory);
                    component.instance.numberCreated = this.container.length;
                    component.instance.men = this.mensajes;
                    // subscribe to component event to know when to delete
                    const selfDeleteSub = component.instance.deleteSelf
                        .pipe(tap(() => component.destroy()))
                        .subscribe();

                    // add subscription to array for clean up
                    this.subs.push(selfDeleteSub);

                }


            },
            error=>{
                console.log(error);
            }
        );


    }

    constructor(private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,private  _chatService:ChatService) {
        this.personas=[
            {id:"2",
                nombre:"sergio"
            },
            {id:"3",
                nombre:"jhoyner"
            },
            {id:"4",
                nombre:"gerardo"
            },
            {id:"5",
                nombre:"fabrizio"
            }
        ]
    }



}
```

app.component.html

```
<div class="sidenav">
  <ul *ngFor="let persona of personas">
    <li><a id="{{persona.id}}"(click)="onClickAdd($event.target)">{{persona.nombre}}</a></li>
  </ul>

</div>
<ng-template #componentsContainer></ng-template>
```

conversacion.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter, Input } from '@angular/core';
import {Mensaje} from "../../models/mensaje";

@Component({
    selector: 'app-conversacion',
    templateUrl: './conversacion.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./conversacion.component.css']
})
export class ConversacionComponent implements OnInit {
    @Output() deleteSelf: EventEmitter<void> = new EventEmitter<void>();
    @Input() numberCreated: number;
    @Input() men:Mensaje[];

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

}
```

conversacion.component.html

```
<button (click)="deleteSelf.emit()" style="background-color: blue; color: white">close window</button>

<p>Number at time of creation: {{ numberCreated }}</p>
<div *ngFor="let message of men">
    {{message.contenido}}--{{message.fecha}}
</div>
<hr>
```

[image]

Comment: You may want to consider maintaining a `Map` with references to all active message windows. This gives you a reusable way to interact with the open windows.  A map would also prevent you from adding duplicate items if you used the id as the key.

Comment: I'm new with Angular,I don't have much idea what you're talking about. Would it be possible to show me what you say in the code I put?

Answer (score 1):

You could just keep track of an array of ids that have already been added and in your onClickAdd method check if the id is already in the array and if it is then don't perform the rest of your method.  Something like the below with the 'alreadyDone' variable:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnDestroy {

    @ViewChild('componentsContainer', { read: ViewContainerRef, static: false }) container: ViewContainerRef;
    private subs: Subscription[] = [];

    public id_usuario_destino:number;
    public personas:Array<any>;
    public id_persona:number;
    public mensajes:Mensaje[];

    public alreadyDone : number[];

    ngOnDestroy() {
        // unsubscribe from all on destroy
        this.subs.forEach(sub => sub.unsubscribe());

    }

    onClickAdd = (elemento) => {
        if(alreadyDone.findIndex(x => x === elemento.id) === -1)
        {
            alreadyDone.push(elemento.id);
            this.id_usuario_destino=elemento.id;
            this.id_persona=this.id_usuario_destino;
            this._chatService.getMessages(1,this.id_usuario_destino).subscribe(
                response=>{
                    if(response.mensajes){
                        this.mensajes=response.mensajes;

                        const factory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(ConversacionComponent);
                        const component = this.container.createComponent(factory);
                        component.instance.numberCreated = this.container.length;
                        component.instance.men = this.mensajes;
                        // subscribe to component event to know when to delete
                        const selfDeleteSub = component.instance.deleteSelf
                            .pipe(tap(() => component.destroy()))
                            .subscribe();

                        // add subscription to array for clean up
                        this.subs.push(selfDeleteSub);

                    }


                },
                error=>{
                    console.log(error);
                }
            );
        }


    }

    constructor(private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,private  _chatService:ChatService) {
        this.personas=[
            {id:"2",
                nombre:"sergio"
            },
            {id:"3",
                nombre:"jhoyner"
            },
            {id:"4",
                nombre:"gerardo"
            },
            {id:"5",
                nombre:"fabrizio"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: In what part of the code would you add that array? Could you tell me more or less how it would be?

Comment: Added more details

Comment: I added your code, but when I click on a user, the console shows "Already.done is undefined", the other problem that I should avoid is that in case I close the window by clicking on the blue button that can be opened again when you select a user again. I don't know if with that idea that you put me you thought about that variant

Comment: I already solved the problem of "undefined" by initializing the empty array in the constructor, the problem that remains is the one I mentioned above, when a box is closed and I want to show it again, it does not show it ... it must be because that id is inside of the array, but how could I remove that element from the array by removing the box?

Comment: I'd probably have to look at your child component code to have any ideas.  You'd probably need to add the elemento.id to your child component and then when destroying the child compnent also remove it from the array.